# Run time error 438: (wks.cells(i, 1))

Tags: stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to paste information from a spreadsheet to a form in my Access database but I get an error at the `Do Until IsEmpty(wks.Cells(i, 1))` line.  I am using Access 2010.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Cmd_Mass_Upload_Click()

If MsgBox("ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO UPDATE RECORDS?", vbOKCancel, "CONFIRM MASS UPDATE") = vbOK Then
    Dim wks
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rsCheckDuplicate As Recordset
    Dim rsUpdateCC As Recordset
    Dim strSQLCheckDuplicate As String
    Dim strUpdateCC As String
    Dim succesfullyUpdated As Integer
    succesfullyUpdated = 0

    i = 1

    'If Me.Ctl2003 = True Then
        Set wks = Me.upLoadSpreadsheet2010
    'End If

    'If Me.Ctl2010 = True Then
    '    Set wks = Me.upLoadSpreadsheet2010
    'End If

    Do Until IsEmpty(wks.Cells(i, 1))

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Set db = CurrentDb

    If i > 1 Then

        For j = 1 To i - 1
            strSQLCheckDuplicate = "SELECT TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[VOUCHER NUMBER], TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[INVOICE NUMBER] " & _
                                "FROM TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS " & _
                                "WHERE (((TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[VOUCHER NUMBER])='" & wks.Cells(j, 1) & "') AND ((TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[INVOICE NUMBER])='" & wks.Cells(j, 2) & "'));"
                                '"WHERE (((TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[VOUCHER NUMBER])='" & wks.Cells(j, 1) & "'));"


            Set rsCheckDuplicate = db.OpenRecordset(strSQLCheckDuplicate)

            If rsCheckDuplicate.EOF Then
                MsgBox "Voucher number " & wks.Cells(j, 1) & " not available in local system!"
            Else
                rsCheckDuplicate.MoveLast
                rsCheckDuplicate.MoveFirst

                If rsCheckDuplicate.RecordCount > 1 Then
                    MsgBox "Voucher number " & wks.Cells(j, 1) & " has multiple entries in local system! Please update manually!"
                End If
                    If Len(wks.Cells(j, 3)) = 6 Then
                        strUpdateCC = "UPDATE TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS SET TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[CHARGE TO] = '" & wks.Cells(j, 3) & "', TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.COMMENTS_NOTES = '" & Form_FRM_MAIN.USER.Caption & ": PART OF MASS UPLOAD ON " & Now() & "' " & _
                                    "WHERE (((TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[VOUCHER NUMBER])='" & wks.Cells(j, 1) & "') AND ((TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[INVOICE NUMBER])='" & wks.Cells(j, 2) & "'));"
                                    '"WHERE (((TBL_OPEN_VOUCHERS.[VOUCHER NUMBER])='" & wks.Cells(j, 1) & "'));"
                        DoCmd.RunSQL strUpdateCC
                        succesfullyUpdated = succesfullyUpdated + 1
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Please check Cost Center"
                    End If
            End If
        Next

    End If
    Set wks = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully uploaded " & succesfullyUpdated & " of " & i - 1 & " records!"
End If

End Sub
Private Sub Command7_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command7_Click


    DoCmd.Close

Exit_Command7_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command7_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command7_Click

End Sub



Private Sub Ctl2003_Click()
    If Me.Ctl2003 = False Then Me.Ctl2010 = True
    If Me.Ctl2003 = True Then Me.Ctl2010 = False
End Sub

Private Sub Ctl2010_Click()
If Me.Ctl2010 = True Then Me.Ctl2003 = False
If Me.Ctl2010 = False Then Me.Ctl2003 = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What was the actual error message you were getting?

Have you tried creating a connection to the spreadsheet as a linked table, then treating the spreadsheet as a table?

Your code doesn't specify the datatype of the "wks" object, so the code doesn't know it is a spreadsheet.

Here's the approach I'd use:

1. Link the spreadsheet as a linked table (External Data, Import Excel Spreadsheet, Link to the DataSource.) This will create a "table" in access which is linked to a spreadsheet that is in a nominated location.
2. Use a query to identify records that are in your linked table but not in your local table (select s.* from upLoadSpreadsheet2010 s left outer join tbl_open_vouchers v on s.somekeycolumnidontknowthenameof = v.[voucher number] and s.someotherkeycolumn = v.[Invoice Number] where v.[voucher number] is null)
3. Open the query in your code, iterate through it, and do you thing, or better still create an Append query to do the job for you without any code at all.

The only challenge then is ensure the excel spreadsheet is in the right place at the right time. New spreadsheet? Just put it in the same place as the last spreadsheet and run the process again.